# how to debug dll in xamarin.forms project

Tags: dll, xamarin.forms

in my xamarin.forms application i have used `zxing.net.mobile` form component for bar code scanner.

now i am trying to capture and save image at time of scanning by changing some code in

> ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android

DLL of .`zxing.net.mobile`

zxing provide open source code in which i made changes.

now i have created separate xamarin.android demo in which i include all code of `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android` with my code change.that run and works fine.saves image successfully.

so now i am trying to this in my project.so by replacing this ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android ref it should work i think.but it is not.

it don't save image and close app abruptly. so whats wrong with this.what i am doing wrong.

i tried to debug updated dll but.it also don't hit `breakpoints` .so cant figure out w.please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check what you can find in the stacktrace when your app crashes

Comment: Method 'ZXing.Mobile.ZXingSurfaceView..ctor' not found.

Comment: is it because i am not linking DLL proper?.what i am doing is right way?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same error: Method 'ZXing.Mobile.ZXingSurfaceView..ctor' not found.

I've installed the Version 2.1.47 via Nuget.

Comment: yes @eiskltereistee . i put .pdb file also with .dll from where i am linking it.it worked for me